# MongoDB Rust driver: 'Files open leak' in my code somewhere

Tags: mongodb, rust

With each successive iteration the following block of code seems to spawn more and more files open so there has to be a leak of that kind somewhere.

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let safe_guard = Arc::new(RwLock::new(Vec::new()));
    loop {
        // Connect to the database
        let client = match Client::with_uri_str(mongo_connection_string).await {
            Ok(o) => o,
            Err(e) => {
                println!("{:?}", e); //the error spam happens here
                tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
                continue;
            }
        };
        let db = client.database(main_db);

        //Setup Handles
        let handle1: Collection<MyStruct> = db.collection(collname1);
        let handle2: Collection<Document> = db.collection(collname2);
        let coll_a = db.collection(collection_a);

        let mut vec_b = vec![];
        let mut coll_b_ = match handle1.find(doc! {}, None).await {
            Ok(x) => x,
            Err(e) => {
                println!("{:?}", e);
                continue;
            }
        };
        while let Some(result) = coll_b_.next().await {
            let s = match result {
                Ok(x) => x,
                Err(e) => {
                    println!("{:?}", e);
                    tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
                    continue;
                }
            };
            vec_b.push(s)
        }

        let mut chats = HashMap::new();
        let mut messages = vec![];
        for s in &vec_b {
            messages.push(s.msg.clone().to_owned());
        }

        let filter = doc! {"msg": {"$in": messages}};
        let mut find_options = FindOptions::default();
        find_options.projection = Some(doc! {
            "msg":1,
            "chat":1
        });
        let mut cursor = match coll_a.find(filter, find_options).await {
            Ok(x) => x,
            Err(e) => {
                println!("ERR");
                tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
                continue;
            }
        };
        while let Some(document) = cursor.next().await {
            let document: Document = match document {
                Ok(d) => d,
                Err(e) => {
                    println!("ERR2");
                    tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
                    continue;
                }
            };
            let user = match document.get("msg") {
                Some(x) => match x.as_str() {
                    Some(x) => x,
                    None => {
                        println!("ERR3");
                        tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
                        continue;
                    }
                },
                None => {
                    println!("ERR4");
                    tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
                    continue;
                }
            };
            let chat_id = match document.get("chat") {
                Some(x) => match x.as_str() {
                    Some(x) => x,
                    None => {
                        println!("ERR5");
                        tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
                        continue;
                    }
                },
                None => {
                    println!("ERR6");
                    tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
                    continue;
                }
            };
            //Insert to HM
            chats.insert(msg.to_owned(), chat.to_owned());
        }

        let coll_handle_handle2 = Arc::new(handle2);
        let coll_handle_handle1 = Arc::new(handle1);
        let handle_handles = Arc::new(chats);
        let handle_safe_guard = Arc::clone(&safe_guard);

        let mut thread_handles = Vec::new();

        //there was a block of code spawning tasks here and awaiting all
        //(if anyone wonders about the lack of logic here)
        //skipping it didn't help
    }
}
```

Getting those errors, starting with: `ConnectionPoolCleared { message: "Connection pool for ... cleared because another operation failed with: Too many open files (os error 24)" }, labels: {"RetryableWriteError"}, wire_version: None, source: None }` and then a spam of: `Error { kind: DnsResolve { message: "io error: Too many open files (os error 24)" }, labels: {}, wire_version: None, source: None }`

I've restarted and called `lsof` repeatedly with sorting and the process seems to be spawning more and more files until the limit is hit.

On MongoDB Compass charts for Mongo Performance this looks like a very steady leak, nothing subsides there, rising slowly to the top even if those operations are empty and there are never more than a few objects in those custom vectors, cursors or structs/HMs.

I'm a bit surprised it spawns that many files open (~1024+ in a span of a minute or so).
And why the iteration going to the next one doesn't drop all the active connections? I don't know what the issue is, I've re-read this a million times focusing on everything that could leave a connection open, tried `drop()` and the like, nothing helps. I do not see any bugs there or I have no clue what this error means.

Edit: "minimal reproducible example". It behaves a bit differently, approaching and crossing the limit, then dissipating below it. The previous never goes below the limit.

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() { 
    let safe_guard:Arc<RwLock<Vec<String>>> = Arc::new(RwLock::new(Vec::new()));

loop{
    // Connect to the database
    let client = match Client::with_uri_str(mongo_connection_string).await{
        Ok(o)=>o,
        Err(e)=>{
            println!("{:?}",e);
            tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
            continue
        }
    };
    let db = client.database(main_db);


    let handle_safe_guard = Arc::clone(&safe_guard);

}
}
```

Even though the code was reduced by +90% I am even more clueless as to why this occurs. I thought this should keep the connections at all times at 1 maximum in theory and it is approaching 1100, dissipating to around 700, then going up again to cross the limit (this repeats).

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] please, there is at least some code wihch does the same and only one of the code paths is enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you meant by "some code which does the same" but I have edited the OP.